# installing ruby with rbenv on Ubuntu server 13.04

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ubuntu, rbenv

Edit1: the link in the answer from  amit karsale is the tutorial I was follwoing originally and does not help me because of the error below

I am trying to use rbenv to install ruby so I can set up rails on my server.  I have been banging my head against the wall and I am sure it is something simple

when I run sudo rbenv install it clones from github and runs for a minute then I get

```
Installing ruby-2.0.0-dev...

BUILD FAILED

Inspect or clean up the working tree at /tmp/ruby-build.20131101165913.25770
Results logged to /tmp/ruby-build.20131101165913.25770.log

Last 10 log lines:
        DLDFLAGS = -fstack-protector -pie
        SOLIBS =
compiling main.c
compiling dmydln.c
compiling dmyencoding.c
compiling version.c
compiling dmyversion.c
generating miniprelude.c
executable host ruby is required. use --with-baseruby option.
make: *** [miniprelude.c] Error 1
```